# How do I properly transfer audio and Video between two PCs

Tags: windows, audio, video

I recently got a laptop from work and want to set it up at home properly besides my desktop computer. My desktop has a microphone, webcam, bluetooth headset, mouse and a keyboard connected to it.
What I want is to use these 5 peripherals on both devices.

I already got [InputDirector](https://www.inputdirector.com/) to use mouse and keyboard on both computers. It got a little noticeable lag but I'm fine with that. However I'm still open for suggestions on how to improve this experience.

My main problem is audio and video.

I want to use the microphone for both devices without the need to unplug it all the time. It doesn't need to be possible to get audio from it at the same time on both devices. Same goes for the webcam. As for the headset it would be nice to be able to hear sound from both computers simultaneously, but that isn't a must have.

For transferring the audio I already tried to connect a 3.5mm jack (headphones out) from my desktop to the 3.5mm jack (microphone in) on the laptop and vice versa. But the quality of the audio is not great. I also tried streaming it via vlc but the latency was really great and I couldn't configure windows to use it as a source.

I'd prefer a software solution for these problems (i.e. streaming it in my home network) but a hardware solution is fine too. I know about kvm's but read that they increase the lag of mice and keyboard which I'd like to avoid since I'm gaming on the desktop.
I'm not very experienced in audio and video streaming/equipment so I'd love to get some ideas and suggestions from the more experienced people.

**EDIT:**
All but the headset are USB devices.

Comment: A KVM will be better than a software solution, likely. Any software solution requiring network communications will have lag, and lots of it. Also, besides hearing about KVMs, what research have you done and what have you tried? Finally, please remove all but one question here. You've got at least two so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the microphone is trivial: use a [3.5 mm Y-connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HD1HC04) with the correct number of wires for your mic and PC's. from the mic to each PC, possibly with an extension cable, if needed. Both devices will get full-quality audio at the same time.

For USB devices, such as an external web-cam or keyboard, to avoid delay of a serial device-to-PC-to-PC connection, the best bet would be to use a [USB device switch selector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MXXQKGM). Only one PC would have access to the devices at a time, though. BTW, do **not** try connecting PC USB's together directly with a double-male cable; that is likely to damage one or both PC USB ports.

The links above are just examples of the sort of devices you might use. Search for your particular needs and desired price range.

Also note that connecting PC's together *via* USB or audio connector may cause a ground loop, resulting in 50 or 60 Hz buzzing and interference. If that occurs, plug all devices into the same power strip, and, if the issue persists and one or more power supply has an unpolarized plug, try reversing one at a time to see if that improves the issue. This is region-dependent; some countries do not have unpolarized plugs, though in North America, they're common.

Comment: I think I'm gonne use the USB device switch selector. As you suggested it makes the most sense.
I didn't know about the buzzing and interference trick. That's neat. Thank you very much!